# How to add a file to my.resources during debug

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

Specifically, I want to add a file to the project resources when running in debug mode.  In other words, during debug, the file info is being built then when finished building the file, I want the VB.net code to programmatically add the file to my.resources before exiting debug mode. I know how to use resx files and how to use  the Visual Studio tools to add a file to resources. However, I need to automate this process during debug.  Anyone have any ideas? Is it even possible?

Thanks

I have searched for several days but cannot find any postings about adding a file to resources during debug mode.

Comment: That's not possible.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of Hans.  Thanks for the input.

Comment: That you're trying to do that indicates a fundamental misunderstanding of what resources are. The whole point is that they are data that is compiled into the assembly itself, so that data cannot be deleted or changed. As such, resources can only be added when the assembly is built.